# Trying to calculate the rate of change in Ruby

Tags: ruby

How would one go about finding the most precise rate of change?

Here's my situation:

- Have a directory that sits empty until a few thousand files dump into it
- Something processes these files, until everything is gone
- I want to figure out how fasts it's processing these files based on when the file gets deleted from the directory.

I know rate of change is: (newamount - oldamount) / time but I'm struggling on the "time" piece.

Here is what I have so far:

```
prev = ""

loop do

  # Let's find the number of files in the input queue, this is a method that basically does a wc -l on a directory.  
  num = number_of_input_files

  # Sleep if there's nothing in 0
  if num.to_i == 0 or prev == ""
    prev = num
    puts "Current: 0"
    sleep 60
    next
  end

  # Find the difference between the current queue number and the previous queue number
  sum = prev.to_i - num.to_i

  puts "Current: #{num}, Previous: #{prev}, Rate #{sum} per minute"

  prev = num

  sleep 60
end
```

I think I'm shooting myself in the foot by the sleep 60, but I'm not sure how to capture a more accurate number. How would I do that?

Comment: I think the`DateTime` class is what you are looking for? http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html

Answer (score 0):

Store the [Time](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html) the script starts processing, and you can check the difference as you go. In short:

```
start = Time.now
# do work
diff = Time.now - start
```

Sleeping would be an issue if this script was both calculating the rate and doing the processing, but since another script is processing, you should be fine.

From the structure of your script, it looks like you'll want to reset `start` whenever the directory becomes empty. You can also calculate the expected time to completion, which I find handy when I'm running these kinds of things.

```
prev = nil

loop do

  # Let's find the number of files in the input queue, this is a method that basically does a wc -l on a directory.  
  num = number_of_input_files.to_i

  # Sleep if there's nothing in 0
  if num == 0 || prev.nil?
    prev = num
    puts "Current: 0"
    start = Time.now
    sleep 60
    next
  end

  # Find the difference between the current queue number and the previous queue number
  sum = prev - num
  diff = (Time.now - start) / 60.0 # per minute
  rate = sum / diff
  remaining = sum / rate

  puts "Current: #{num}, Previous: #{prev}, Rate #{rate} per minute"
  puts "#{remaining} minutes remaining"

  prev = num

  sleep 60
end
```

`sum` is going to be negative for one cycle whenever a batch of work is dumped into the directory, so you might want to account for that too.